# Jquery change class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to a change a class for a span located inside an h3 but I am unable to. Here is a link to what I am trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/WPxG4/9/

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('h3').click(function() {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        $(this).next('span').toggleClass('special1', 'special');
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<h3><span class="special"></span><a href="#">Heading 1</a></h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">List one two there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List one two there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List one two there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List one two there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List one two there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List one two there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List one two there</a></li>
</ul>
```

​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(this).find('span')` **not** `$(this).next('span')`

Comment: @user1238850 your welcome ^_^. Remember to select an accepted answer here and on your other questions if you had any.

Comment: @Neal http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions